# does not support Arabic Content in webpage

Tags: php, mysql

Hi All I am creating Arabic website. But problem is that it does not support the Arabic content. it comes ???????????? . Even I put charset="utf-8" in .htaccess. I also put meta tag in every page. I saved the files as utf-8 support file format. Even I put there `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`
 MySQL Stored data shown in Arabic language but if I put some Arabic language in tag it wont support

Somebody have some idea regarding this because this is my firs Arabic website.

Comment: the problem is when you insert data using PHP?

Comment: ref this link you will get some idea about encoding : http://kunststube.net/encoding/

Comment: @Akam please visit this site www.aldaleelinstitute.com/ar/

Comment: did you do: "SET NAMES UTF8" ?

Comment: What is the encoding of your source text? Can you get the text to display properly by switching the display encoding in your browser? (In Chrome, View > Encoding > ...)

Comment: Hey Can you show us the code what you have written?

Comment: you have to add this after mysql_select_db(): mysql_query('SET NAMES UTF8'); then tell us if you tested...

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//AR">
<html lang="ar" dir="rtl" >
<head >
<title>معهد الدليل</title>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type"  CONTENT="text/html; CHARSET=iso-8859-6">

Comment: @Akam data fetched through the MySQL shows in Arabic format problem is the written inside the page wont shows. it shows ??????

Comment: are u sure? what I see is that data came from db is not shown because of invalid encoding, if you not follow the instruction here, then, why asking?

Comment: @Akam thanks akam I put the code it works in index.php but rest page still shows ??????????

Comment: put the code directly after mysql_select_db(); you must use one dbconnect file for all pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with adding meta charset for arabic at the begning

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type"  CONTENT="text/html; CHARSET=iso-8859-6">
```

Or you may try it out with following steps :-

```
Displaying Arabic text using PHP

1. Don't use the short tags <? ?>. Use the full tags <?php ?>

2. Remove the quotes and semicolon from the first line and others that are outside the php tags
"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">";

3. Close the span tag <span lang='ar-kw'

4. Make sure save the file with utf-8 encoding. You might be saving it with another coding.
```

Comment: Why would you specify a doctype of `EN` on a non-English page?

Comment: the encoding is fine, see there is arabic text on the site (static) while dynamic text from db not shown...

Comment: @ScoRpion hi its work in first page but I copied and past the code the rest page not working.

Comment: @ukdub when it worked with first page and you copied the code to all pages, it should work, I would suggest you to create a layout page and put this code there and then inherit that page in your other pages

Comment: That's incorrect meta for Arabic, Mark Ormston's meta is better and it actually works with everything.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely want to add extra designations to your HTML. For example, if you are using HTML 5, it will look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
:
your content here
:
```

Comment: This is not the solution see the source code of the page there is no valid text!!!

Comment: Sorry, the link was not there for the page when I started this answer and didn't notice it while I was typing it up.

Answer (score 1):

Change the structure of the field Collation to: `UTF8 general CI`